# Using Razor script to randomly pick a page node in Umbraco

Tags: macros, razor, umbraco

The following code displays a testimonial item on the homepage of http://www.keelycattschoolofdance.co.uk which works nicely:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines;
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{ 
var numberOfItems = 1;
DynamicNodeList pages = @Model.Children.Where("umbracoNaviHide !=    true").Take(numberOfItems).OrderBy("UpdateDate");
}

<div>
    @foreach (DynamicNode page in pages)
    {        
       <h2>@page.Name</h2>
       <p>@page.GetProperty("introText")</p>
       <p><a href="@page.Url">Read more...</a></p>
       <p><strong>@page.GetProperty("personsName")</strong></p>                       
    }
</div>
```

I would like to take this little script a stage further by selecting a random testimonial. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var r = new Random();
var numberOfItems = 1;
List<DynamicNode> pages = new DynamicNode(Model.Id).Descendants().Items.Where(x => x.Visible).OrderBy(x => r.Next()).Take(numberOfItems).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks although not entirely sure it works though. It may be because at the moment there are only two items to randomise and as we add more, it will work better perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the method of using Linq to generate random meta data and then sorting by it.

```
IPublishedContent containerNode = Umbraco.TypedContent(1144);
IPublishedContent randomlySelectedChildNode = containerNode.Children.OrderBy(n => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
```

There is also a built-in Umbraco extension you can use:

```
var randomNode = containerNode.Children.RandomOrder().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the **ElementAt**() Linq method:

```
Random r = new Random();
int max = 10;   // set your own max

var items = @Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants("SomeNode").First().Descendants("SomeChildNode").First().Children;
var item = items.ElementAt(r.Next(0, max));  // use linq ElementAt to retrieve your random node
```